# Python re: negating part of a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Perhaps a silly question, but though google returned lots of similar cases, I could not find this exact situation: what regular expression will match all string NOT containing a particular string. For example, I want to match any string that does not contain 'foo_'.
Now,

```
 re.match('(?<!foo_).*', 'foo_bar')
```

returns a match. While

```
re.match('(?<!foo_)bar', 'foo_bar')
```

does not.
I tried the non-greedy version:

```
 re.match('(?<!foo_).*?', 'foo_bar')
```

still returns a match. 
If I add more characters after the ),

```
re.search('(?<!foo_)b.*', 'foo_bar')
```

it returns None, but if the target string has more trailing chars:

```
re.search('(?<!foo_)b.*', 'foo_barbaric')
```

it returns a match.
I intentionally kept out the initial .* or .*? in the re. But same thing happens with that.

Any ideas why this strange behaviour? (I need this as a single regular expression - to be entered as a user input).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using lookbehind assertions where you need lookahead assertions:

```
re.match(r"(?!.*foo_).*", "foo_bar")
```

would work (i. e. not match).

`(?!.*foo_)` means "Assert that it is impossible to match `.*foo_` from the current position in the string. Since you're using `re.match()`, that position is automatically defined as the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried look ahead with .*(?!foo_).* which did not work. Missed out the ".*" after the "?!" .

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern instead:

```
^(?!.*foo_).*
```

This uses the `^` metacharacter to match from the beginning of the string, and then uses a negative look-ahead that checks for "foo_". If it exists, the match will fail.

Since you gave examples using both `re.match()` and `re.search()`, the above pattern would work with both approaches. However, when you're using `re.match()` you can safely omit the usage of the `^` metacharacter since it will match at the beginning of the string, unlike `re.search()` which matches anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is a good chance that you could just design around this with a conditional statement.

(It would be nice if we knew specifically what you're trying to accomplish).

Why not:

```
if not re.match("foo", something):
    do_something
else:
    print "SKipping this"
```

Comment: Since the OP wants it to fail if 'foo_' is anywhere in the string, you should be using `search` instead of `match`, or better yet just not even use regex: `if 'foo_' not in some_string:`

Comment: Err, excellent point.  I guess I was just thinking of returning something on a negative result.

Personally I think that "if not" is a lot more readable than the other solutions posted, and readability is really important to me.